# How to determine the concrete type of the parameterizedType of injected CDI bean

Tags: java, generics, jpa-2.0, cdi, jboss-weld

To make a long story short, I have these classes

```
public class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private BaseService<T> service;
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public void init() {
        Type arg = ((ParameterizedType) ((Class) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        persistentClass = (Class<T>) arg;
    }

    // Other stuff
}

public interface BaseService<T extends BaseEntity> {
}

public class BaseServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements BaseService<T>, Serializable {
    private Class<T> queryClass;
    public BaseServiceImpl(){
        // Set the above queryClass through Java Reflection and/or CDI. Stucked here!
    }
}
```

When I subclass the BaseController such like

```
public class PersonController extends BaseController<Person, Long> {

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

The persistentClass is assigned with Person class which is correct, I also want to determine the concrete type class in BaseServiceImpl too, to set queryClass variable in it. How can I do that?
Thanks.
**Update:** More details,
The BaseController needs persistentClass to create new instances from it (persistentClass.newInstance()) and some reflection stuff like to get declared methods and annotations in JPA entity class.

The BaseService needs queryClass (which must be the same as persistentClass) to actually delegate it to underlying DAO layer, which in turn the DAO class simply uses it in

```
entityManager.find(queryClass, id);
```

and similar operations.
Both BaseController and BaseService (and BaseDAO) are common for most entity CRUD pages/operations.

Comment: What is it you _actually_ need to know, and why?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Added more detail.

Comment: @UlukBiy Inject a factory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is inject a `BaseServiceFactory` instead of the actual `BaseService<T>` as follows:

```
public interface BaseServiceFactory {

    <T> BaseService<T> create(Class<T> queryClass);
}

public class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private BaseServiceFactory<T> serviceFactory;
// .
// .
// .
}
```

then modify your BaseServiceImpl constructor as follows:

```
public class BaseServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity>
    implements BaseService<T>, Serializable {
    private final Class<T> queryClass;

    public BaseServiceImpl(Class<T> queryClass){
        this.queryClass = queryClass;
    }
}
```

and then get the appropriately typed class as follows:

```
BaseService<T> service = serviceFactory.create(persistentClass);
```

Comment: Thanks for input however I could not see the implementation of create method. If there the new BaseServiceImpl will be returned then I think I will lose the benefits of CDI.

Comment: Please elaborate on "I will lose the benefits of CDI". You can implement the create method to suit your needs. i.e. arrange for the factory to create a single instance and return that instance to all calls.

Comment: I cannot use the factory pattern right now cause the class structure is more complicated than that in the question. However yours answers this question.

Comment: do you have the solution somewhere online posted? I am dealing with something similar, any help would be highly appreciated!